# How to create custom structured nodes in TYPO3 Neos?

Tags: neoscms

I would like to create custom nodes with editables properties, like TCA in TYPO3 CMS or CCK in Drupal.

How I could define the custom node type so I could create objects, which will be used further in my extensions ?

There is an official way ? Examples ?

Answer (score 0):

Creating custom nodes/content elements is described in the official documentation here http://docs.typo3.org/neos/TYPO3NeosDocumentation/IntegratorGuide/CustomContentElements.html

Comment: As I undertand, CustomContentElements it's kind of TYPO3 CMS Flexform, isn't it ? I need something kind of BE List records with autogenerated form. Confirm, please.

Comment: I guess you could say that Custom Content Elements is kind of like flexforms, but not quite. If you need the Neos analogy of BE List records with autogenerated forms (like TCAForms), that is something different. Neos does not have a "List" module currently, although there was once a project called Expose which did something like that. I am not sure what the status of that is. But in my experience, you can often use Content elements for what you need, but you need to think it a little bit different than CMS where everything is tables and records.

Comment: I think, Expose is what I need. I have found this FlowPackExpose http://flowpackexpose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/. It's not exactly Neos, but Flow and Doctrine, so, logically is compatible with Neos. Am I right ?